# SQLite record read in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am getting different value (in case of unicode value) than what it should suppose to be. Here is the explanation: I am storing value 'îî' and when I run the select command from terminal (connected to .sqlite file) I am able to see the the exact value. But when I am trying to fetch the value programmatically I seeing a complete different value. This is the code I am reading and storing the value in char pointer.

Comment: add code to your question so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it should be  UTF-8. 
You can try with different another encoding like ascii,MACRoman etc.
`[NSString stringWithCString:st encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Note: You can verify UNICODE value by printing value in console.